# ffmpeg error when cutting video (aac bitstream error)

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to use ffmpeg to cut out a 5 minute chunk from a video.  For some reason on this particular video I get an error "aac bitstream error".  The resulting video is 5 minutes long with no audio or video.

```
ffmpeg -i testvideo.mp4 -ss 00:05:00 -t 00:10:00 -c:v copy -c:a copy testvideo_5min_test.mp4
ffmpeg version N-55540-g93f4277 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Aug 14 2013 12:15:34 with gcc 4.3.2 (Debian 4.3.2-1.1)
  configuration: --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-shared --enable-libfaac --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      52. 42.100 / 52. 42.100
  libavcodec     55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
  libavformat    55. 13.102 / 55. 13.102
  libavdevice    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
  libavfilter     3. 82.100 /  3. 82.100
  libswscale      2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libswresample   0. 17.103 /  0. 17.103
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'testvideo.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    creation_time   : 2013-05-10 17:42:36
  Duration: 00:35:21.47, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 8684 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 8490 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 29970 tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-05-10 17:42:36
      handler_name    : Mainconcept MP4 Video Media Handler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-05-10 17:42:36
      handler_name    : Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
File 'testvideo_5min_test.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, mp4, to 'testvideo_5min_test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.13.102
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 8490 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29970 tbn, 29970 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-05-10 17:42:36
      handler_name    : Mainconcept MP4 Video Media Handler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, 189 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-05-10 17:42:36
      handler_name    : Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mp4 @ 0x8088740] aac bitstream error5886kB time=00:01:13.63 bitrate=8442.8kbits/s    
[mp4 @ 0x8088740] aac bitstream error8357kB time=00:04:15.24 bitrate=8612.9kbits/s    
[mp4 @ 0x8088740] aac bitstream error6128kB time=00:05:00.25 bitrate=8625.0kbits/s    
[mp4 @ 0x8088740] aac bitstream error6415kB time=00:07:12.56 bitrate=8643.7kbits/s    
frame=17952 fps=2429 q=-1.0 Lsize=  635531kB time=00:10:00.01 bitrate=8677.0kbits/s    
video:621056kB audio:13870kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.095223%
```

Comment: Does the resulting file play ok?

Comment: I mentioned in my original post: "The resulting video is 5 minutes long with no audio or video."  It's just black, no audio or video.

Comment: I've tested the same video and command on another server with ffmpeg and it works fine.  Any ideas what could be mis-configured here?